# Looking for a video downloader in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: video, 22.04

This is my second attempt to migrate to Ubuntu 22.04. Everything is fine, but I am missing a tool for downloading videos from the internet.

I am looking for an app with a graphical user interface that allows me to download videos from websites.

Comment: in firefox click on the hamburger meny upper right corner,click on addons and search for vdeo downloader and simply add it to firefox.you will now have an icon on the top of your screen where you can select the video you want to download.it is as simple as that no terminal needed to do this.

Comment: I've added some further clarification to the question and requested it be re-opened as it is entirely valid and the answer provided by @kanehekili is equally valid.

Comment: What tool and in what OS are you trying to replace?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download videos with Ubuntu, you might take my [downloader](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader) into consideration. It has been developed for Linux with the very simple interface.

[image]

The tool can be downloaded and installed with one command.

Or using my ppa. Setup:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jentiger-moratai/mediatools
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ytdownloader
```

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: @26401 "The one command" refers to the download. You do not need that command if you install my repository as explained in the answer

Comment: just used your download tool on my new instance of 22.04 after following your installation instructions and it works perfectly - thank you. I've requested the question be re-opened since your answer achieves what the OP has requested.

Comment: added to my previous comment, features I like particularly are the ability to build a list of URLs for download in one hit and the ability to change the download directory. An easy application for a novice user.

Comment: @kanehekili after downloading the .tar file and following your instructions to extract it ` sudo ./install.sh` I see no launcher for the program in the `ytdownloader` folder. How do I actually run it from there?

Comment: There should be a launcher deployed in /usr/share/applications: YtGui.desktop. Go to "activities" and enter "yt" - the launcher should be there

Comment: Nope, don't see that in `/usr/share/applications`  There is another alternative -  I could add the repo manually just need the name of the repository I want to add in the format (eg) `deb http://packages.domain.com/ bookworm main`

Comment: bullseye: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jentiger-moratai/mediatools/ubuntu jammy main.. You might replace jammy with "kinetic". But the tar.gz includes the desktop file.. What happens if you start YtGui from commandline?

Comment: @kanehekili command not found. Don't worry about it. I'm going to spin up a version of Debian 12 and see what happens there. I l know it works on Ubuntu because I already installed it there. Thanks for the responses anyway 

Comment: The deb version will install its own yt-dlp version, so it should not be installed via apt. But I still don't understand why the install.sh didn't work. That is distro agnostic...