# Youtube-dl / yt-dlp stuck on "Downloading webpage"

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I have problems downloading any video using `youtube-dl` on Ubuntu 20.04.

Whenever I try to download a video, the progress is stuck at `Downloading webpage`. Then I wait and nothing happens...

```
youtube-dl --verbose https://youtu.be/IMxN6tocjX0
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['--verbose', 'https://youtu.be/IMxN6tocjX0']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, out utf-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2021.12.17
[debug] Python version 3.8.3 (CPython) - Linux-5.15.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.10
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 4.2.7, ffprobe 4.2.7, rtmpdump 2.4
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[youtube] IMxN6tocjX0: Downloading webpage
```

I have the most current version available via `pip` (2021.12.17).

I also tried with a current version of `yt-dlp` (2022.08.19), but same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, it seems to have been a problem with IPv6. Running `youtube-dl` with the flag

```
--force-ipv4
```

worked for me.

The same flag also works for the same issue with `yt-dlp`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes YT update their system which can cause issues with `youtube-dl` which is why, often third party apps suggest a refresh.

For me, downloading videos from YT is best served with the app `Youtube Downloader` which includes an option to update when required.

[This answer on AU](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410302/307670) explains the steps to install the app.

The simple instructions are reproduces below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jentiger-moratai/mediatools
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ytdownloader
```

[image]

The [image] icon updates to the latest yt-dlp.

Acknowledgements to AU user [kanehekill](https://askubuntu.com/users/906933/kanehekili)