# how do I fix youtube-dl: running it gives error message about incorrect syntax

Tags: 22.04, downloads, wget, youtube-dl, syntax

I recently installed 22.04 completely from scratch. Just now I followed instructions to install youtube-dl, with wget (from github.com):

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

It seemed to download, but upon using it, it says this:

```
$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSyDTIAX_oE
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: line 1: --2023-03-05: command not found
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: line 2: `Resolving yt-dl.org (yt-dl.org)... 95.143.172.170, 2001:1a50:11:0:5f:8f:acaa:177'
```

I am not sure if I am even giving enough/appropriate information for asking my question. Please advise me if I should explain something else.
Apparently youtube-dl was not working for a while but the website says it's fine again. I don't know if that might be part of the problem?

I tried these commands as suggested:

```
file /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with very long lines (564)

head /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
--2023-03-05 12:38:51--  https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl
Resolving yt-dl.org (yt-dl.org)... 95.143.172.170, 2001:1a50:11:0:5f:8f:acaa:177
Connecting to yt-dl.org (yt-dl.org)|95.143.172.170|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2021.12.17/youtube-dl [following]
--2023-03-05 12:38:52--  https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2021.12.17/youtube-dl
Reusing existing connection to yt-dl.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases/download/2021.12.17/youtube-dl [following]
--2023-03-05 12:38:52--  https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases/download/2021.12.17/youtube-dl
```

Comment: what does `file /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` and `head /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` say? I suspect you've somehow managed to `wget` an html page or something, not the actual youtube-dl script.

Comment: Why not make life easy and download [Youtube Downloader](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410302/307670) as outlined in this post by another ask ubuntu subscriber. I use it almost daily.

Comment: `Just now I followed instructions to install youtube-dl` -- Which instructions? Please edit the post and describe what you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found youtube-dl to be outdated, so I found a solution at:

```
https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-youtube-dl-linux-use
```

I installed:

```
pip3 install yt-dlp
```

It works OK:

yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtube-dl_has_made_the_world_better

Comment: Yes I agree. They appear to have stopped developing it. yt-dlp is being kept up to date.

Comment: And https://clipgrab.org uses yt-dlp and clipGrab works for me on Ubu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

try this

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall "git+https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git"`

source:
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/31530#issuecomment-1435477247

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your youtube-dl download was incomplete, and the `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` contains the error messages instead of the actual binary. First, delete it.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Then, install it with python3-pip.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user youtube-dl
```

Finally, you may have to run `source .bashrc` so that the youtube-dl executible is within `$PATH`.

Comment: I have python/pip problems so my quick fix was to download t https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/archive/master.tar.gz   unzip it and run it from that location using sh yt-dlp.sh  <url>   there were some audio issues though and it was downloading in partial files then periodically adding to the one that would play whilst downloading. $PATH setting as above would be an improvement

Comment: and for multiple urls I save to list.txt and run as for i in $(cat list.txt); do sh yt-dlp.sh  "$i" ;done   

no problems now with the previous errors. downloading is erratic in bandwidth usage though but it worked