# Internet works for everything except YouTube

Tags: internet, youtube

When I try to start YouTube sometimes it shows 'Please connect to the internet' after loading the page. Every other site I have tried works perfectly. :

[image: This a screenshot of what I see]

To try to solve this, I have tried to change the MTU on the router settings. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't for all values.

for example when the MTU is set to 1490 and YouTube is not loading I change it to 1500 and it starts working sometimes and then again it stops working, so when I change it back to 1490 it starts working again sometimes. I have contacted my ISP. They say it's a problem with my router, but this doesn't happen with my router when set up with a different network. This happens only for one particular laptop, and all the other devices are working fine.

When I ping [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) everything seems to be fine.

[image: Here's the image]

This is what I get when I try to use yt-dlp to download a video.

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: Are you living in China, North Korea, Iran, Turkmenistan, Sudan, Syria, Tajikistan or Uzbekistan? 

Can you download youtube videos from the command line using yt-dlp, or is it just the website that is not working?

Comment: I am from India. I haven't tried it yet, I have tried to ping youtube.com, it didn't workout. The next time it stops working I will try it and add the results.

Comment: I have edited the question to include more details

Comment: @User1986 Please help

Comment: It seems like youtube is not able to be reached. 

Have you tried using a vpn, (or an online proxy)? does the problem persist across mutiple devices?

Comment: No the problem is only with my laptop, alll the other devices seem to be working fine. My laptop works fine on other networks, Youtube works fine via vpn.

Comment: The problem doesn't occur all the timw

Comment: I can't quite figure out what the problem is - but completely reinstalling ubuntu should fix it IF its not hardware related.

Would that be a large inconvenience?

Comment: It is somewhat of an inconvenience, I will still try it after backing up my data.

Comment: Just for sake of completeness. I have tried update and upgrade, that didn't fix the issue though.  Thanks a lot for your time though.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457872/how-do-i-fix-youtube-dl-running-it-gives-error-message-about-incorrect-syntax/1458930#1458930

Comment: This smells like a browser bug. Which web browser are you using? Does it work fine with a different browser? Since it shows part of the YouTube website, I'm guessing that some sort of problem is occurring while the page is loading, causing the website to crash in your browser. If you really want to get to the bottom of it, or if switching web browsers doesn't work, open the Developer Tools (usually F12) before navigating to the YouTube website. It should show some interesting messages in the console; or it might stop at an exception/breakpoint if things are going wrong.